# Creating a simple name value mapper class in C#

Tags: c#

I want to create a class (static?) that simply maps a name to a value (1 to 1). What's a clean way of doing something like this:

```
public static class FieldMapper
{
  public static GetValue(string Name)
  {
    if (Name == "abc")
        return "Value1";

    if (Name == "def")
        return "Value2";
  }
}
```

I might be having a mind block today. I am unable to think of a clean solution for a simple problem like this :(

**Edit:
All the values are known at compile time (There is no uniqueness - different keys can map to same value). I shouldn't be creating a datastructure that adds values at runtime. Also, I would like to avoid using a XML file**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the collection to be created at compile time instead of at startup, you could just use a switch.

If the switch contains more than a few items (five IIRC) it's implemented using a hash lookup, so it's very fast even if you put a lot of cases in it. (I.e. the access time is the same for any of the cases.)

```
public static class FieldMapper {

   public static string GetValue(string name) {
      switch (name) {
         case "abc": return "Value1";
         case "def": return "Value2";
      }
      throw new ArgumentException("Unknown name.", "name");
   }
}
```

Answer (score 14):

Sounds like a job for a dictionary.

```
Dictionary<string, string> values = new Dictionary<string, string>();
values.Add("abc", "Value1");
values.Add("def", "Value2");
Console.WriteLine(values["abc"]);   // Prints "Value1"
```

Comment: A class that inherits from IDictionary? All these values are known at compile time.

Comment: In .Net 2 or higher, System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<TKey, TValue>

Answer (score 1):

You are describing a [Hash Table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) data structure. These are typically implemented using a [hashing function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function).

C# already has this type of data structure implemented. See the [IDictionary Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.idictionary.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

If you can pre-load your items into a dictionary, that would help considerably:

```
IDictionary<string, string> myValues = new Dictionary<string, string>( 3 )
{
        {"abc", "Value1"},
        {"def", "Value2"},
        {"ghi", "Value3"}
};

var mySearchString = "abc";
return myValues.Keys.Contains( "abc" ) ? myValues[ mySearchString ] : string.Empty;
```

Comment: Is it required to specify the number of elements in the dictionary or is this optional. Though I know all the items during design time, there will be several devs updating the file and it's error prone to expect them to increment the number whenever they add a new one

Comment: Robert's right. There are several overloads on the Dictionary (and other similar collection types), one of which allows you to set the number of items ahead of time if you know it. This overload is available because if you know that number, it'll make the Dictionary that much more efficient.

Comment: @Boydski, to clarify: if you pass a size into a List or Dictionary, you aren't specifying the size, just the initial capacity.

Comment: Exactly. Which is that much less overhead during the addition of new items to the collection until the collection exceeds that initializer. The overload is there for a reason. {-o)

Comment: If you know the capacity you need when you create the dictionary you should of course specify it, but if you don't the overhead is quite low. The average overhead is to copy a few extra bytes each time you add an item to the dictionary, so it's rarely even noticable.

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about values known at compile-time, you could try storing them as resources. Something like this:

```
//Name Spaces Required
using System.Resources;
using System.Reflection;

// Create the resource manager.
Assembly assembly = this.GetType().Assembly;

//ResFile.Strings -> <Namespace>.<ResourceFileName i.e. Strings.resx>
resman = new ResourceManager("StringResources.Strings", assembly);

// Load the value of string value for Client
strClientName = resman.GetString("Client");
```

(Stolen from [here](http://snipplr.com/view/2140/csharp-reading-string-from-resource-file--------------------/))

Comment: aka Dictionary<string, object> maybe?

Comment: If you vote down, let me know why -- if my answers are wrong, I can correct them or remove them.

Comment: I didn't but a List<kvp> isn't a hashlookup, it doesn't solve the problem

Comment: If both your keys and values are strings, using resources aren't out of the question.

Answer (score 0):

I think a dictionary would be better but, if you were going to do it in code:

```
 public static class FieldMapper
{  
     public static GetValue(string Name)  
    {    
       switch (Name)
      {
        case "abc":
         return Value1;
      }
    }
}
```